# Can a single-member LLC have a fiscal year not as the calendar year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, limited-liability-company, california

Well, the title pretty much is the question. I'm in California, and its a disregarded entity. It matters for the LLC tax, and a positive answer will save me $800 cash. With references please, though:-) Couldn't find anything decisive on the FTB side, they write a lot of words, but the essence is pretty elusive.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no tax expert by any means. I do know that a disreagarded entity is considered a sole proprietor for [federal tax purposes](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/article/0,,id=158625,00.html).

My understanding is that this means your personal tax year and your business tax year must be one and the same.

Nevertheless, it is technically possible to have a non-calendar fiscal year as an individual. This is so rare that I'm unable to find a an IRS reference to this. The best reference I could find was [this article](http://www.allbusiness.com/government/business-regulations/320411-1.html) written by two CPAs.

If you really want to persue this, you basically need to talk with an accountant, since this is complicated, and required keeping propper accounting records for your personal life, in addition to your business. A ledger creqated after-the-fact by an accountant has been ruled insufficent. You really need to live by the fiscal year you choose.